# CSS Code for Table Headers that are static with a fluid width table

Tags: html, css, head

Does anyone have css code and/or table structure for a fluid width table with fixed headers. The table could potentially scroll if the contents are bigger then the table height. The table is fluid width. This is for a sharepoint web part but the web part is custom so no need to think about sharepoint's native css.

Thanks!

One more thing. THe main problem is I don't know when there is going to be a scroll bar or not so it messes with the headers.

Fixed headers are headers that don't scroll, when you scroll through the TBODY

Comment: probably put your comment into the post. Hit edit and add that in.

Comment: By default, the height of a HTML table automatically adjusts so that the whole contents are shown. Is your table in a div/iframe with a fixed height?

Comment: and what exactly do you mean by "fixed headers" - do the headers stay put even when you scroll the rest of the content?

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to data tables it is best not to reinvent the wheel.  They can get extraordinarily complicated very quickly.  Fortunately their are a variety of different offerings out there with zounds of features.

http://www.datatables.net/

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/datatable/

http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/aspnet/web-hierarchical-data-grid.aspx#Overview

... just to name a few.

Answer (score 0):

Won't a good jQuery fixed header plugin do the trick for you?